# Add numbers to a field in a file

Tags: text-processing

I have a file and some of the data looks like this:

```
Archie McNichol:(206) 548-1348:250:100:175
```

I want to take the 175 at the end and add 100 to it, so it will print out to this:

```
Archie McNichol:(206) 548-1348:250:100:275
```

This is really all I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=: read -r -a LINE
do
    added=${LINE[3]} | 100
    echo "${LINE[0]}" $added+100

done < "$1"
```

Comment: `awk -F: '{$NF += 100}1' file`

Answer (score 2):

As jasonwryan comments:

```
$ awk -F: '{$NF += 100}1' file
```

or, corrected for an obvious omission (`OFS`) and written in the way I would write it,

```
$ awk -v FS=':' -v OFS=':' '{ $NF += 100 } { print }' file >file.new
```

or,

```
$ awk -v FS=':' -v OFS=':' '{ $NF += 100; print }' file >file.new
```

This will read from `file` and will create a new file called `file.new`.

This short `awk` script treats each line of `file` as consisting of `:`-delimited fields. With `$NF` we may access the last field of each line and with `$NF += 100` we add 100 to whatever its value is.

The `print` will output the modified line (`1` in the comment solution is a truth value that prompts `awk` to perform the default action of printing the current line).

The command line options `-v FS=':' -v OFS=':'` sets both the input and output field separators to `:`.

Testing it with a single line of input:

```
$ echo 'Archie McNichol:(206) 548-1348:250:100:175' | awk -v FS=':' -v OFS=':' '{ $NF += 100 } { print }'
Archie McNichol:(206) 548-1348:250:100:275
```